# Why does syntax of the property setter have a ":" at the end

Tags: objective-c

The syntax of the property setter from what I have tried so far is this.

`@property (setter=m_set_m_var:,getter=n_set_m_var,nonatomic)  int my_var;`

My question is why does the setter property only have `:` in the end ?

Comment: it means the setter expects a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setter and getter attributes are selectors, or method names. The : is there to mark where an argument is expected. If you were to declare these methods manually they'd look like this:

```
- (void)m_set_m_var:(int)var;
- (int)n_set_m_var;
```

Only the setter needs an argument, and thus only that one has a colon.

Comment: It doesn't need a colon.

Comment: @trojanfoe Could you expand on that? I wouldn't mind learning something new... at least I get a compiler error if I don't put it there.

Comment: What you say is certainly true if you manually define the setter/getter methods, however the `@property` setter attribute doesn't need the colon to be there.  What the OP says is incorrect.